# Spring boot / Thymeleaf - Getting Time from input

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to get Date and Time using separate inputs from a form.
So far getting the date is working, however getting time (hour and minutes) using
 results in an error.
Here's part of my entity class:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private Date start_date;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "HH:mm")
private Date start_hour;
```

Here's the part of the form I'm using to get data from user:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <label th:attr="for='start_date_'+${subject.id}">Start Date</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="date" th:attr="id='start_date_'+${subject.id}" th:field="*{start_date}"/>
     </div>
     <div class="col-6">
         <label th:attr="for='start_time_'+${subject.id}">Start hour</label>
         <input class="form-control" type="time" th:attr="id='start_time_'+${subject.id}" th:field="*{start_hour}"/>
      </div>
</div>
```

I keep getting an error:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Validation failed for object='lesson'. Error count: 1
```

I tested the date input and time inputs separately and it's the time input that's giving me trouble.

Comment: Check the @InitBinder documents ,it will be helpful to solve iyour problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change data types to

`java.sql.Date` and `java.sql.Time`

Or if you are on Java 8

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE)
private LocalDate start_date;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
@DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.TIME)
private LocalDateTime start_hour;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your error maybe it is caused by a [Validation Layer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html) that it is rejecting your object. I recommend you to try to debug or print the error list and see what kind of error is rejecting your request.