# ThymeLeaf time issue with Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am stuck with a rather so called simple issue. 
I have html field for time. I want to save the time in database from user input.

my html input:

> `<input type="time" th:field="*{startTime}"/>`

I tried with different approach in model class.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
.....
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
@DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.TIME)
private LocalDateTime startTime;
```

This results in error while starting the application : @Temporal should only be set on a java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar.

I tried with first removing the @Temporal, and then with

```
import java.sql.Time;
....
private Time startTime;
```

In both occasion upon saving the form I am getting error : Validation failed for object='process'. Error count: 1

I was referring to the accepted answer in this post - [Spring boot / Thymeleaf - Getting Time from input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45291061/spring-boot-thymeleaf-getting-time-from-input)

Kindly help.

**UPDATE**: the pom.xml dependencies and entire error

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
>   /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Sun Jul 29 02:27:39 CEST 2018 There was an unexpected error (type=Bad
>   Request, status=400). Validation failed for object='process'. Error
>   count: 1

Comment: This is not a Thymeleaf problem, it's a Hibernate problem. If you're using the included Hibernate dependencies, you may need to include the `hibernate-java8` dependency to get time support.

Comment: @chrylis: Thanks for replying. But are you sure ? Although deprecated, I just tried with adding both `hibernate-java8` and the suggested `hibernate-core` dependency. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Post your POM file (and also your entire stack trace, not just the summary line); for example, *what* validation error occurred?

Comment: @chrylis: Updated. I had other text field in the form, only after adding this time filed I am getting this error. Have one `java.sql.Date` field as well, all except the time field works fine.

Comment: When you get that "whitelabel" page, you should also get a much more detailed error report on the Java console.

Comment: You didn't show your _entire_ POM (e.g., no versions), but check your dependency tree and see if it's pulling in this Thymeleaf module. If not, add it, and that may fix your problem: https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-java8time

Comment: I wish, but no! No error on the console :(

Comment: Then set `log.level.org.springframework.web: DEBUG`.

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, I have 'solved' it using

```
<input type="datetime-local" th:field="*{time}"/>
```

And in the model class

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm")
private LocalDateTime time;
```

I referred the first answer given in this post - [Spring with Thymeleaf binding date in html form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45629318/spring-with-thymeleaf-binding-date-in-html-form)

Comment: You want, apparently, only time. Then why use `LocalDateTime` instead of `LocalTime`?